# Image is not getting saved in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js

Through `node.js` i want to save a file from the request but while writing the file it is giving `undefined` error. And in directory it is giving blank file.

File received from API:

```
D:\varahi.png
```

Node.js code:

```
if (req.body.attachment !== undefined) {
    var base64Data = req.body.attachment;
    var filePath = "./public/images/LabourKhurakiExpense/" + billImage + ".png";
    var fileURL = "/images/LabourKhurakiExpense/" + billImage + ".png";
    //console.log('writing file...', base64Data);
    fs.writeFile(filePath, base64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
    imageURL = fileURL;
} else {
    imageURL = null;
}
```

Comment: `it is giving undefined error` - can you please show the **exact** error - not just some vague description of the error

Comment: @JaromandaX I mean file is getting saved in the path but when we try to open it it is saying file can't open

Comment: Did you check the permission first?

Comment: @JohnC what kind of permission

Comment: Remember that writeFile is async

Comment: @debashishdwivedi File permission and Folder permission. Are you permitted to do this and that on that specific location?

Comment: @JohnC Yes all are permitted

Comment: perhaps it's `billImage` that is `undefined` ... you still haven't shown the actual error message you are getting though - does `base64Data` look like base 64 data?

Comment: Save path `filePath` and `imageURL` are not the same path, why you can open it? you may edit your code more complete.